The meaning of ''as also'' in the given paragraph?

Pakistan Nationals as also "persons resident outside Pakistan" holding Pakistani securities
desirous of sending or taking out the Pakistani securities not covered under the succeeding paragraphs 6 & 7 are required to obtain prior permission of the State Bank. Application for the purpose should be made to the State Bank through an Authorized Dealer.

What is the meaning of 'as also' in the above paragraph? Does it mean Pakistan nationals who are residing outside Pakistan or is it talking about two categories of persons - Pakistan Nationals and Persons residing outside Pakistan?

From the context of the document "as also" means "as well as", including two groups in the rule.
From point 1 of the source text:

[...] the term "a person resident outside Pakistan" covers a foreign national including a foreign national of Indo-Pakistan origin as also a Pakistani holding dual nationality for the time being resident in Pakistan [...]


Agreed. But I’ll add that A as also B can carry a nuance of highlighting a similarity between A and B. Thus, whereas Boys and girls like candy is neutral about anything more than taste for candy, Boys as also girls like candy can mean something like Boys and girls share an attribute, which is a fondness for candy.
